# Change Title Tag in Typo3

Tags: php, web

I want to change the ereg method in PHP.

I tried to use `preg_match` without succsess.

Can anybody helb me to change this code :

```
if (ereg("/$", $pref) === FALSE) {
    $pref .= '/';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if(strpos($pred, "/") !== false) {
   echo "true";
}
```

Its a bit faster because you don't need regex and the FSM-Mashine.

Comment: This does not have the same behaviour as the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry ;) i have forgotten to remove the ending

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet checks whether the string `$pref` ends with a slash. You can easily check the same by using `substr()`:

```
if (substr($pref, -1) != '/') {
    $pref .= '/';
}
```

or even shorter:

```
$pref .= (substr($pref, -1) != '/' ? '/' : '');
```